# Two ng repeat for same row in angular js for single table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two array data I want to display first array data in first column and second array data in second column using ng-repeat in single table

```
        //First array data
$scope.users = [{name: "Jack", age: 10},{name: "Bart",age: 20}, {name: "Griffin",age: 40}];

    //Second array data
    $scope.user1 = [
       {lang: "JAva"}, 
       {lang: "C"}, 
       {lang: "C++"}];

//Expected output:
        Name-----Lang
        Jack     Java
        Bart     C
        Griffin  C++
```

Is it possible tried using two ng-repeat but first ng-repeat is displayed?

Comment: are the two arrays of the same length?

Comment: no for eg i gave with same lenght

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You arrays definition is not so clear to me.  I tried to come up with this. I re-compose a new array and just ng-repeat once.  Hope I understand correct

HTML

```
<div ng-app='testapp'>
    <div ng-controller='testCtrl'>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat='entry in repeatData'>
                <td>{{entry.user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{entry.lang.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

the controller

```
var app = angular.module('testapp', []);

app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.nameArray = [{name: "Jack", age: 10},{name: "Bart",age: 20}, {name: "Griffin",age: 40}];

    $scope.langArray = [{name: "JAva"}, {name: "C"}, {name: "C++"}];


    $scope.repeatData = $scope.nameArray.map(function(value, index) {
        return {
            user: value,
            lang: $scope.langArray[index]
        }
    });
});
```

see this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7hj40vdh/)

#### Updated

If it cannot be combined, you can try to use $index

```
<div ng-repeat='user in users'>
    {{user.name}} {{user1[$index].lang}}
</div>
```

Something like this.  Make sure your array length is correct.

Comment: Thank you but the two array should not combined

Comment: If it cannot be combined, you can use $index.  See updated.